# How to add a custom WordPress PDF file link

Tags: wordpress, pdf, permalinks

I have a WordPress website. I want to add a PDF file in my site. and i want the permalink to me custom. I want to change the permalink of the PDF file according to my requirements.

What can i do.

Thank You.

Comment: What does the link have to look like ? In a default WP installation, all medias are uploaded to `/wp-content/uploads`.

Comment: the link is look like `code`http://www.yoursite.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Price-List.pdf`code`
i want the link to be link this `code`http://www.yoursite.com/Price-List.pdf`code`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may upload your file to the root of your FTP server; Wordpress does not provide an easy way to do what you want.

Comment: thank you, but how can i rename the location in the wordpress?

Comment: Thank You To All. I DID IT. 
Thanks